# File input field is not 100% active

Tags: html, css, file, input, field

I have custom file attach field. It works fine but there's a little thing that needs to be fixed: the right side of the field is completely inactive. Also, if you move your cursor over top-left corner you can notice that this part is apparently active but CSS "cursor: pointer" option doesn't have an effect. Pretty sure I missed something simple, tell me please what is my mistake? Thank you in advance. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c7d6w0te/)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,500&subset=cyrillic');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-weight: 100;
  background: #333;
}

body a {
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.file-area {
  width: 450px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}
.file-area input[type=file] {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.file-area .file-dummy {
  width: 450px;
  padding: 30px;
  background: rgba(75, 58, 38, 0.3);
  border: 1px dashed rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.file-area .file-dummy .success {
  display: none;
}
.file-area:hover .file-dummy {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
.file-area input[type=file]:focus + .file-dummy {
  outline: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
  outline: none;
}
.file-area input[type=file]:valid + .file-dummy {
  border-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.4);
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2);
}
.file-area input[type=file]:valid + .file-dummy .success {
  display: inline-block;
}
.file-area input[type=file]:valid + .file-dummy .default {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="file-area">  
    <input type="file" name="files" id="files" required="required"/>
    <div class="file-dummy">
      <span class="default">Choose files</span>
      <span class="success">Yahoo!</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: because your ```.file-area``` class have fixed width.

Comment: @KOKOC I think you have to remove `cursor: pointer` and make it the default since the top left file browser will have an effect on the pointer so that you have to use the same pointer value.

Comment: Thanks to you and other guys, but is this any way to spread "cursor: pointer" effect on a whole block? Pointer finger still turns into cursor if I hover it over top-left box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just removed the width from `.file-area` and seems working fine.

============ Latest Changes ================

Just for making the `cursor: pointer` trick changed `font-size:0;`

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,500&subset=cyrillic');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-family: "Roboto";
 font-weight: 100;
 background: #333;
}

 body a {
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
 }
 
#container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
}

.file-area {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}
.file-area input[type=file] {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size:0;
}
.file-area .file-dummy {
  width: 450px;
  padding: 30px;
  background: rgba(75, 58, 38, 0.3);
  border: 1px dashed rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.file-area .file-dummy .success {
  display: none;
}
.file-area:hover .file-dummy {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
.file-area input[type=file]:focus + .file-dummy {
  outline: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
  outline: none;
}
.file-area input[type=file]:valid + .file-dummy {
  border-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.4);
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2);
}
.file-area input[type=file]:valid + .file-dummy .success {
  display: inline-block;
}
.file-area input[type=file]:valid + .file-dummy .default {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div class="file-area">  
  <input type="file" name="files" id="files" required="required"/>
  <div class="file-dummy">
   <span class="default">Choose files</span>
   <span class="success">Yahoo!</span>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks to you and other guys, but is this any way to spread "cursor: pointer" effect on a whole block? Pointer finger still turns into cursor if I hover it over top-left box.

Comment: Sorry didn't follow you. What you want now?

Comment: My mistake, sorry. I've made an explanatory screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ma64z.png If you move your mouse on top-left area, the cursor turns into default. The effect of "cursor: pointer" disappears right here, but it works on remaining areas of DIV. I can't get what should I do to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is only because of the fixed `width` in the class `file-area`, try to remove the width, hope it will fix your issue

[Updated Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/c7d6w0te/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the width from the `.file-dummy` and it should be solved

```css
.file-area .file-dummy {
width: 450px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit your .file-area class width to 100%

Comment: In this case the block goes left and a clickable space appears from the right side of it. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You add `padding` & apply `width 100%`, padding include width.

Change width like this way `width: calc(100% - 60px);`

```
.file-area .file-dummy {
    background: rgba(75, 58, 38, 0.3) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px dashed rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    width: calc(100% - 60px);
}
```